# Hosting multiple websites in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, architecture, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

We currently have 30 individual drupal websites hosted on a single physical server running CentOS-7 and Apache, there is no load balancer or scaling mechanism in place. We do take regular backups though.

We are planning to migrate our setup to cloud services such as AWS. In view of that, we have the following queries:

1. What is the best practice to host all these websites on AWS?
2. Is it recommended to have separate docker containers for each website? If so, should we have the database of each website in separate RDS?

Answer (score 3):

There are many valid ways that you could move your Drupal sites into the AWS cloud but personally I would use [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-drupal-website/) which will provide you with auto-scaling and fault tolerance if you run it in at least 2 Availability Zones.

I would recommend a local memcached (can be installed with [.ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) on instance startup) or [Elasticache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) for best Drupal performance.

Placing [Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) in front of your Drupal Elastic Beanstalk app will further improve performance.

The choice to share or not share an RDS deployment really depends on utilization, cost, performance needs and whether or not you want these 30 sites to be coupled (RDS issue takes down all sites). It's hard to make a recommendation here without understanding the nature of the 30 sites and your goals for them.